# Why using stack container is slower?

Tags: java, performance, stack

I 'm trying to solve problem 739, Daily Temperatures on LeetCode.
https://leetcode.com/problems/daily-temperatures/

My code used Stack container provided by the JAVA. It takes 60 ms to run. This is my code:

```
class Solution {
    public int[] dailyTemperatures(int[] T) {
        int[] ret = new int[T.length];
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i < T.length; i++){
            while(!stack.isEmpty() && T[i] > T[stack.peek()]){
                int index = stack.pop();
                ret[index] = i - index;             
            }
            stack.push(i);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Here is a code that only takes 6ms to run:

```
class Solution {
    public int[] dailyTemperatures(int[] T) {

        int[] temperatures = T;
        if(temperatures == null) return null;

        int[] result = new int[temperatures.length];
        int[] stack = new int[temperatures.length];
        int top = 0;
        stack[top] = -1;

        for(int i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++) {
            while(stack[top] != -1 && temperatures[i] > temperatures[stack[top]]) {
                int index = stack[top--];
                result[index] = i - index;
            }

            stack[++top] = i;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Why building the stack using an array is faster than using the stack container?

Comment: Autoboxing, perhaps.

Comment: @rjdkolb

Your edit replaced the first code with the second, making them the same. Rolled back.

Comment: You can test if it's caused by autoboxing by using an `Integer[]` for the 2nd example.

Comment: @Wentao Wang, What input are you using ? int[] input = {73, 74, 75, 71, 69, 72, 76, 73}; takes 0 ms for both examples on my PC using Java 11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java's [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) is a **very** old class, introduced back in JDK 1.0. It extends [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html), and all it's data manipulation methods are `synchronized`, creating a very sizeable performance overhead. While it isn't officially deprecated, it's outdated, and you really shouldn't be using it in this day and age. The modern [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) provides the same functionality without the synchronization overhead.

Comment: Once the JIT warms up, the synchronization wouldn't have an effect: escape analysis would determine the synchronization to be unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks! Is the ArrayDeque class unsafe under the multithreads context?

Comment: @WentaoWang No, it isn't. You could use [`LinkedBlockingDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html) if you need a thread-safe implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Tested in the leetcode environment:

1. the first `Stack[Integer]` solution takes 80ms to run, and changing `Stack[Integer]` to `ArrayDeque[Integer]` takes 31ms. Which is a great improvement, which can prove that `Stack` is much slower than the morden `ArrayDeque`.

Note that only the `pop` method and `peek` are `synchronized`, while the `push` is not.

2. the second `array[]` solution takes 10ms in my run. and chaning to `Integer[]`
    takes 19ms. So I think autoboxing is also a factor.

So there are not a single reason for this.

Comment: Are you seeing the same times on a local JVM using System.currentTimeMillis() ? My experiments show 0 ms for both using int[] input = {73, 74, 75, 71, 69, 72, 76, 73};

Comment: No, leetcode tests the code for multiple inputs, and sum the executing time up.

Comment: Since your input is small, it is reasonable that it only costs nearly 0 ms, perhaps we can test it with a VERY large input on our local machine.

Comment: To improve your answer it would be nice to simulate multiple inputs in a local JVM with a profiler and visually show this

Answer (score 0):

Only profiling will show you exactly which effects are the source of the slower running time.

My best guest would be the creation of Boxing-Integer-Intances for the `int` values and the much more complex implementation of

`stack.pop()` / `stack.peek()`  / `stack.push()`  in contrast to elementary array-accesses.

You could try to change your array version to use `Integer` instead and look how the performance changes.